# Difference between deployment and provisioning ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Whenever I create a new pipeline in ADF, and click on 'deploy', at first I see the message saying **"deplyoing"**, right after that I see the message saying **"provisioning"**. What's the difference?

Can we have a situation where it is deploying the pipeline but not provisioning?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case provisioning is a part of the deployment process.

When you start deployment of solutions like ADF, Azure will initiate provisioning of the needed resources, for example creation of virtual machines, storage accounts etc.

Once the correct resources have been provisioned, the selected solution(s) will then be installed and configured on the resource(s).

In more general terms:

> ‘Deployment’ is the process of putting a new application, or new version of an application, onto a prepared application server.
>
> If you are talking to a developer, it may also mean the process of preparing the server, perhaps by installing libraries or daemons. If you are talking to an operations professional, it DOES NOT. They use the word “provisioning” for that.
>
> (Developers are going to keep using the word “deploy” for everything involved in getting our app and its dependencies installed. That’s cool. But don’t be surprised if you confuse your Ops guy.)
>
> The word ‘Provisioning’ is normally used by Ops folks to refer to getting computers or virtual hosts to use, and installing needed libraries or services on them. They use the word for a lot of other things as well, such as buying access to network bandwidth, but you can probably ignore that.
>
> The thing to remember is that ‘deployment’ does not, as a rule, include ‘provisioning’.

(more details here: http://codefol.io/posts/deployment-versus-provisioning-versus-orchestration)

Comment: Thanks, that's why I think when you only edit a given ADF and click on Deploy, it doesn't say "Provisioning" again, it only says "Deploying..", because the resources it needs are already available probably.

Comment: Exactly, that should be the reason.